# Running the app on Android console Error - Jdeveloper

Tags: android-emulator, oracle-adf

I am using `JDeveloper 11g Release 2`. I am trying to run a `helloworld` code on the `Android simulator`. But i end up having the following error in the console. This is due to some settings that i have failed to set. Can someone help me to add the settings so i could run the app on the Android Console.

```
The following Android preference configuration is missing or invalid. Set these options in JDeveloper Preferences on the ADF Mobile panel:
Key and Keystore Password
Android SDK Location
Android Platform Location
 (oracle.adfmf.framework.dt.deploy.android.deployers.ValidatePreferencesDeployer)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't keystore for signing android apps right now as for testing purpose. You should select build mode to `Debug` rather than `Release` mode.

Application > Application Properties > Deployment > select your android build profiles or create a new one > Click at `Edit` button > Android Option > Change `Build Mode` to `Debug`

Comment: I have the same issue and mine already has the build mode set to debug, is there anything else that would cause the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the Android SDK for Android development and Xcode for iOS development.
FAQ for ADF Mobile: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/adf/learnmore/adfmobilefaq-1866697.pdf

Here you can find the setup guide for Android :
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18941_01/tutorials/MobileTutorial/jdtut_11r2_54_2.html

And the one for iOS :
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18941_01/tutorials/MobileTutorial/jdtut_11r2_54_1.html

For Android, make sure your emulator emulates version 4.0 or higher in order to avoid :

```
The Android emulator emulates ARMv5, which is not supported. The emulator must support ARMv6 or newer
```

Comment: I have done Android development using eclipse, and i have all the SDKs installed. But how can i point the Android SDK (which i have already installed) in Oracle JDeveloper ?

Comment: @Illep In your JDev > Tools > Preferences > ADF Mobile > Platforms. There you can set the location of your SDK's

Comment: I set the Android SDK location (`C:\Android\android-sdk`) and Platform location (`C:\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-13`). Now i get this error `The Android emulator emulates ARMv5, which is not supported.  The emulator must support ARMv6 or newer. (oracle.adfmf.framework.dt.deploy.android.deployers.CheckAttachedDevicesDeployer)`. How can i correct this ?

Comment: @Illep I haven't done any android development but can't you update your Android emulator/sdk by using the android manager?

Comment: This document (http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html) says it only supports ARMv5, but Oracle will not add the 'run using android emulator feature' if it's unable to run in the emulator. There has to be some workaround, but i am clueless :(

Comment: @Illep You can find your answer here : http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18941_01/tutorials/MobileTutorial/jdtut_11r2_54_2.html (view step 4)

Comment: Note that it seems that you are mixing two concepts - The android setting in JDeveloper are for building ADF Mobile applications (which can run on Android and on iOS). This is totally different from doing pure Java development for Android.

Answer (score 0):

If there is also an error above this stating that it can't write the cwallet.sso try closing Jdeveloper and running as administrator.